# How to implement MQTT on Zephyr OS with cellular devices?

Tags: c, mqtt, microcontroller, firmware, zephyr-rtos

I am a beginner on Zephyr OS and wanted to know if it is possible to implement MQTT on Zephyr OS with Cellular Devices like SIM800 or Quectel BG96 that usually work on UART and support TCP protocol which is the base of MQTT.

I looked through the example for MQTT given for Zephyr which is done over LAN but could not figure out how to implement the same with a cellular device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MQTT itself does not necessitate TCP as the transport layer but you may need one transport layer. Most of the implementation out there are relying on TCP as the transport layer e.g.:

- [Paho MQTT Client C Library](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/c/)
- [Paho MQTT Client C++ Library](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/cpp/)

There is an implementation that only serializes and deserializes MQTT compliant packages. But this implementation is based on the MQTT-SN (sensor-network) standard and needs a MQTT-SN compliant MQTT-gateway or MQTT-Broker. Theses packages you may transfer as you like: As UART stream, memory map IO, etc.

- [Paho MQTT-SN Package C Library](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/c/embedded-sn/)

In addition, check to implement and provide a TCP/IP socket to a MQTT client Library that wraps the AT Command specification of both devices:

- [**AT Commands for TCPIP Application Toolkit**](https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM800/SIM800%20Series_AT%20Command%20Manual_V1.10.pdf)
- [**BG96 TCP/IP AT Commands Manual**](https://www.quectel.com/UploadImage/Downlad/Quectel_BG96_TCP(IP)_AT_Commands_Manual_V1.0.pdf)

Comment: Thank you @fisehara, I looked into the MQTT Client Library, where the read write methods are to be implemented, which can be over any transport layer.

Implementing those methods and sending the packet to the cellular device that is configured for TCP should work.